# Error installing visual studio service pack 1

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am trying to install visual studio 2008 service pack 1

I am got following error with visual studio Just-In-Time debugger

Error-An Handled Exception ('System.TypeLoadException') occurred in ServiceModelReg.exe[900]

Can you help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Services

Disable IIS admin service while installing it..